# How does InputStream buffer work?

Tags: java, android, buffer

I'm using a `InputStream` buffer as following. I'd like to know when it is actually buffering (filling itself with data)... I'm feeding it with internet stream. I put `Log`s before and after `len = in.read(buffer)` but they are logged in the same time (so the process is not here).

```
    conn = new URL(StringUrls[0]).openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    in = conn.getInputStream();
    int len=-1;
    buffer = new byte[1024];

    Log.v("buffer", "buffering...");

    len = in.read(buffer);

    Log.v("buffer", "buffered");
```

Comment: Can you please share the logs ? I am expecting there is a minute difference in milliseconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) states:

`This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.`

In other words, it is being filled when it has the data to be filed with.
When you open a connection, the data are ready to be read. That is why `InputStream` does not have to wait for anything.